# Powerstrip ground pin broke off. Is it now a DIY isolation transformer?

Tags: mains

Would it ever be safe to use this to isolate appliances from ground?

Comment: It not a transformer of any kind.  It is a dangerous piece of broken junk, that lets you plug in equipment that expects to be grounded but that doesn't actually provide the needed ground connection.

Comment: I'm not going to actually plug it in, but don't isolation transformers isolate you from ground? Isn't that their purpose?

Comment: No, they isolate the *power source* from ground. Remember, the power is normally grounded at the service entrance, which is what makes it dangerous if you are grounded and you touch a live wire. An isolation transformer breaks that circuit.

Comment: If you play with that, you are handing in your submission for a Darwin Award... So: Don’t..

Answer (score 11):

Absolutely not! The household hot line is still directly connected to the outlets in the power strip.

In fact, it is closer to the opposite. You have no isolation and no safety ground on the devices plugged in!

Do you think they would make isolation transformers if isolation were that simple?

Comment: _"You have no isolation and no safety ground on the devices plugged in!"_ - I think it's worth stressing more that the broken power strip really is the worst of both worlds ;)